# How can I join three SQL with two table having the same field ne

Tags: mysql, sql, php-7

I have three tables

```
Student
-------------
id,
matno,
Surname,
faculty_id,
dept_id,
....

Faculty
------------
id,
name,
...

department
-------------------
id,
name,
....
```

I want to select student details using **matno** plus the name of faculty and name of department using faculty_id and dept_id . I have tried all SQL JOIN combinations i can think of and I only get one name field.

Also I get null on second query if I try to fetch query using different statement.

### Edited

My SQL query is

```
SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN faculty ON faculty.id = student.faculty_id LEFT JOIN department ON  department.id = student.dept_id WHERE student.matno = 1104
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `faculty_id` and `dept_id` are foreign keys into the `Faculty` and `department` tables, this query should give you your desired result (replace `???` with the desired search value of `matno`):

```
SELECT s.matno, s.surname, f.name AS faculty, d.name AS department
FROM Student s
JOIN Faculty f ON f.id = s.faculty_id
JOIN department d ON d.id = s.dept_id
WHERE matno = ???
```

Comment: @StanleyAloh try these: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
STUDENT S
LEFT JOIN FACULTY F
ON S.FACULTY_ID = F.ID
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT D
ON S.DEPT_ID = D.ID WHERE S.MATNO = "$your_matno";
```

Try using this left join so that at least all students will be in the result set and select the required fields from it.

Comment: This is not valid php code, and even if it were, it's still very dangerous and not safe against sql injection. It might not run on Linux because of case sensitivity mismatch

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, name column is still one